# Twilio Hangup: charge for call Id

Tags: javascript, twilio

I'm developing an application using twilio and during development I have been using the following script to grab the Caller Id from a client. It was working a treat until I realised that if you answer the call and hangup immediately you are charged for a minute. Is there anyway to grab the callId without answering during development so I'm not charged every time I need to test my code? Any thoughts appreciated.

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
  var resp = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
  resp.hangup();
  var callId = req.body.From
  res.type('text/xml');
  res.send(resp.toString());
  res.end(//send callId);
});
```

Comment: It's definitely possible; this example shows how to reject calls without answering based on caller id: http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/reject (and the description specifically mentions not being billed for the call)

Comment: resp.reject(); was what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colin Pickard got it...

```
resp.reject();
```